# display 'auto' on react native not working

Tags: css, react-native, display

i want hide element after i changed opacity with animation. when i set display 'none' it working and hide element, but when i use `display:'auto'` or `display:''` it not working and crash android app

here is my code sample:

```
export default class FadeInOut extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  { 
                    visibleChild: this.props.animShow,
                    opacityVal: new Animated.Value(visiChangeG ? 1 : 0),
                  }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!visiChangeG) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.opacityVal, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: this.props.animDuration,
        useNativeDriver: true 
      }).start();
    }

    if (visiChangeG) {
      Animated.timing(this.state.opacityVal, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: this.props.animDuration,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }).start();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Animated.View
          pointerEvents={visiChangeG ? 'auto' : 'none'}
          style={[{width:300, height:300, display: ''},  //it not working and crashing android app
                   {opacity: this.state.opacityVal}]}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Animated.View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

how can solve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use display: 'flex' when you want to make the component visible again.
In react native, display only supports 'none' and 'flex'. 'flex' is the default value.

I hope it works for you.